# How to change the value of a CSS key at runtime from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a fairly simple page which queries a web service to pull data from a SQL server, returning a generic list of varying size. What I'm trying to do, is adjust the height of the div at runtime, adding a certain number of pixels to an existing CSS key on each iteration of a foreach loop, so that the projected list does not overflow the container div.

The code I am using to put the list on the page is as follows:

```
int total = 0;
lstUsageServices.Text = string.Empty;
lstUsageRequests.Text = string.Empty;
if (txtAccount.Text != string.Empty)
{
soapClient = new UsageService.ServiceSoapClient();
foreach (UsageClient.UsageService.Usage current in soapClient.GetUsage(txtAccount.Text, startPicker.SelectedDate, endPicker.SelectedDate))
{
lstUsageServices.Text += current.Service + "<br />";
lstUsageRequests.Text += current.Requests.ToString() + "<br />";
total += current.Requests;                        
}
lstUsageServices.Text += "<strong>Total</strong>";
lstUsageRequests.Text += "<strong>" + total.ToString() + "</strong>";
```

What I would like to do, is add a line inside the foreach to reference a div:

```
<div class="main" runat="server" id="mainDiv">
```

and increase the CSS "height:Xpx;" with each iteration.

I hope someone can help, it doesn't seem like this should be a difficult thing to do! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want the `div`'s height to increase as it gets more content, can't you just leave its height as automatic?

Comment: tried leaving as auto, doesn't seem to be honoured, even when i add a !important

Answer (score 2):

A simple way  can be

```
mainDiv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", "Xpx");
```

Comment: The idea is correct; the OP will need to calculate X then assign it after the loop.

Comment: that's fine, so I'll just keep a count of the number of rows, and multiply the count by the number of pixels a row occupies. Will it not be an issue that I'll be constantly adding more attributes, will the most recent simply replace the previous one?

Comment: no joy on this unfortunateley, added the below to now avail

    mainDiv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", (420 + (rowCount * 10)).ToString());

Comment: ended up instead using an <asp:Literal> control, which DOES force the height of a div if set to auto.